# C# doesn't catch execute non query exception

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code that calls the stored procedure to 'insert' data to tables in SQL.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Global_Variables.DBcon))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_WinApps_Import_ERData", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("file imported!");
    }

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BATCH ID ALREADY EXISTS!" + ex.Message );
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

but the problem is, it doesn't catch the error in the 'try-catch method' i dont know why but my code is correct.

The Error says: "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'Cons_BatchID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_WinApps_FileHeader'.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: What error are you referring to.

Comment: Can you paste the exception message here?

Comment: Is there an Inner Exception?

Comment: i just updated my post :)

Comment: exception is clear. You have specified "UNIQUE KEY" constraint on some of your table column.

Comment: yeah i know that, what i want is to actually catch that error.

Comment: You need to display the _full_ exception. You have no idea what type the exception is. Never use `ex.Message` if you care what happened. Use `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: To your question, I don't see a single thing that is wrong other than you should have conn.Open() inside the try{}. The error you are getting though should be getting caught, so you have me stumped. MSDN documentation indicates you should still have a Catch(Exception ex){} at the bottom. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it guys. Go to Debug > Exceptions and i just 'unchecked thrown checkbox' in Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: This will not help you if your Program ran not in Visual Studio -_-

Comment: @Smartis No, it is a misunderstanding. The OP thought an error wasn't being caught. It was, but Visual Studio would break on the immediate cause of the exception. This option stops that. Had the OP stepped through the code he would have seen the catch working as expected (assuming it was a `SqlException`).